# I installed the python3.8 version for my application and deleted the python2.7 in amazon linux 2 , now yum command is not working

Tags: yum, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

[image]
I installed the python3.8 version for my application and deleted the python2.7 in amazon linux 2 , now yum command is not working.

Comment: reinstall Python 2.7. Multiple Python version can co-exist. for your application, learn how to use "venv"

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Do you have "dnf" installed? It may not work for the same reason "yum" won't work - or it might not exist Amazon LInux 2.  In fact you may have a hard time anything. I'd recommend contacting AWS to see if they can re-install it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you have not deleted the actual file and have just deleted the link the `/usr/bin/python`

**Assuming that is the case**

Check what all python are present in the directory by
`ls /usr/bin/python*`

If python 2.7 is present then create a symlink for the same by

**Backup `usr/bin/python` first**

You can create symlink by

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```